# Remove antialiasing on Highcharts curves

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, antialiasing

With HighCharts, I want to remove anti-aliasing on SVG curves.

So far, I'm using this :

```
$('path').each(function(i,j){$(j).attr('shape-rendering', 'crispEdges')})
```

And I was wondering if the was a better way, i.e. is there something implemented in Highcharts API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shape-rendering is a CSS property so you can set it for all paths using

```
path {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

[Like this for instance](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/vhN5B/).

It's also inherited so if you set it on a parent or root element all the children get it.

If you're working in SVG document then

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
```

might work for you.

There is a highcharts [shape-rendering suggestion](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1230033-set-svg-shape-rendering-property) you can vote for if you want this to be part of highcharts itself.

Comment: This should be the ideal solution, but actually it doesn't work.. :/

Comment: Are you displaying the chart in a html page? I've expanded my answer to cover that case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't have API for that attribute, but you can set this a little similar, and should be faster: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/163/

```
                $("#container path").attr({
                    'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges'
                });
```